# Right Place for Discussion - Meal Prep

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

First off, let me start by saying this is my first post on **ANY** Meta page so if this is off-topic or not the right place, let me know and I can delete it.

I was wondering if Seasoned Advice was the correct place to discuss or seek information on Meal Prep (Strategies, insights, etc.)? I have googled, and learned a bit there. But in seeing the passion of some of the people here getting their advice would be great too. If this is not the correct place, any suggestions?

Comment: Asking/discussing about the the scope of the site is one of the goals of any site’s Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the main site is the correct place for this sort of discussion.

However, as I am sure you have, given your reputation; please read the `help center` and keep the questions specific/on-topic. Broad questions seeking opinion are usually not on-topic (though often discussed widely).

Comment: I figured I would start with a broad scope on the Meta and then actually write my question (in more detail, less opinion based) on the main page - if this topic were deemed appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed you would. I just realized that in my post above I was talking about posts on the main page, not on here, just in case you were wondering.